# Background loads slowly when page switches

Tags: http, css, twitter-bootstrap

Today when I wrote css I found that there are some problems appearing. I used bootstrap and darkstrap to design. In darkstrap the body's style is

```
body {
        color: #c6c6c6;
        background-color: #2f2f2f;
}
```

And in my own css:

```
body {
        background: url(../img/11.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%
}
```

It looks no problem but the only question is when I switch the page, the page seems to have an asynchronous load (but I didn't refresh the page), first completing the style in darkstrap, then loading my style after 1 second. But I put my css before the bootstrap and darkstrap. And I just not refresh the page.

At last, I quote the body style in darkstrap, when I switch the page again, the body's `background-color` also complete after 1 seconds, it looks awful, I know the image load may send a http request and its loading may last. But I just switch the page... so where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you loading the scripts and css? Is it and the end of the page body?

One way to fix this might be to move the script loading into the page `<head>` section. When you do this, all of it will be loaded **before** any body markup. This will ensure that your CSS and the bootstrap css is ready before you see anything on the page. The downside of this is that it might make the page *appear* to take longer to load.

There could be other reasons, but this is the first thing that sprang to mind for me.